# Issue with static code in Android

Tags: java, android, static

I am building my own class, which is similar to an Enum. Here's the code:

```
public final class MyClass {
    public final static MyClass V1 = new MyClass("v1");
    public final static MyClass V2 = new MyClass("v2");
    public final static MyClass V3 = new MyClass("v3");

    private static Map<String, MyClass> values;
    private final String name;

    private MyClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        if (values == null)
            values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put(name,this);
    }

    public static MyClass[] values() {
        return values.values().toArray(new MyClass[values.size()]);
    }

    public static MyClass valueOf(String key) {        
        return values.get(key);    
    }

    public String getName() {        
        return name;    
    }

    public String toString() { 
        return getName(); 
    }

    public static void print() {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, MyClass>> i = values.entrySet().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            String key = i.next().getKey();
            System.out.println(MyClass.class.getSimpleName() + ": " + key + ", " + values.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

I am observing a weird behavior: when I try to invoke `MyClass.valueOf("v1")` I get `null`. 
I tried to debug and:

- the constructor is invoked long before `valueOf` is invoked (when I invoke print, it gets invoked 3 times)
- `values` gets populated (last constructor invocation, of course, takes the map size to 3, as expected.
- when in `valueOf`, `values` is empty

====UPDATE

**ONLY if I am in debug mode and put a breakpoint in the print method, then I can see the "enum-like-class" values printed in the console. When I do htis, `valueOf` returns the correct results.**

What's happening?

Comment: Works for me. Not using Android, but in plain-ol-Java it works fine.

Comment: Could be an issue with the android class loader and static values, since classes are not always unloaded when you leave the application. Even so, the code looks fine to me. But try without using `static`, and see if it behaves any better.

Comment: Actually, it is having such behavior randomly...

Comment: I have two identical classes: for MyClass I experiment the described issue. For the other one I don't.

Comment: Randomness is getting worse. I updated my OP.

Comment: any reason why you are reinventing enums?

Comment: Yes: Java does not support hierarchies of enums and I need one. The enum I reported is a leaf, but it actually extends another enum.

Comment: can you add logs to your constructor, so then you should be able to find when it creates instances and when it tries to access your map, what is weird for me, is you are using lazy instantiate of static map in you class constructor. so if your instance is not created, valueOf should throw NPE. unless it is some concurrency  issue, which explains why you have random behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the best way I found to tackle the issue is to move values definition and initialization before the other static variables.
This way, it gets initialized before the constructors are invoked.

Look at this: [Static initializer not called on Activity creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297662/static-initializer-not-called-on-activity-creation/35297732#35297732)