# Static initializer not called on Activity creation

Tags: java, android, static

I have the following code in my main Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        MyClass[] arr = MyClass.values();
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

MyClass is as follow:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static MyClass A;
    public static MyClass B;
    public static MyClass C;

    static {
        System.out.println("Invoked");
        A = new MyClass("a");
        B = new MyClass("b");
        C = new MyClass("c");
    }

    private static Map<String, MyClass> values = null;
    private final String name;

    private MyClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        if (values == null)
            values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put(name, this);
    }

    public static MyClass[] values() {
        return values.values().toArray(new MyClass[values.size()]);
    }
}
```

My issue is that `values()` triggers a `NullPointerException`, as `values` is null, i.e. the static initialization block seems not to be invoked. Nevertheless, the console out "Invoked" appers, so the initialization block DOES get called.

What's wrong?

EDIT: this question is strictly related to this: [Issue with static code in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279064/issue-with-static-code-in-android)

Comment: `values` isn't initialized by the static initializer block... why not assign a new `HashMap` to it straight away?

Comment: The static initializer invokes the constructor, which initilizes is.

Comment: Also, if I do initilize it in the static block, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `private static Map<String, MyClass> values = null;` is after the static initializer: this assignment will be run *after* the static initializer block, so it is being assigned a non-null value, and then nulled out.

Move the `values` field before the initializer block.

---

BTW, I would decouple the creation of the instances from inserting them into the map, in order to remove the side effects when creating an instance of `MyClass`. You can also do it without a static initializer block:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final Map<String, MyClass> values = new HashMap<>();

    public static final MyClass A = register(new MyClass("a"));
    public static final MyClass B = register(new MyClass("b"));
    public static final MyClass C = register(new MyClass("c"));

    private static MyClass register(MyClass instance) {
      values.put(instance.name, instance);
      return instance;
    }

    private MyClass(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Actually, I wouldn't even do this: I'd use an `enum` - but I guess there is something in your real code that stops you from doing that.

Comment: Thanks, that is very interesting and moving my variable definition at the beginning fixes my issue. However, I am not sure that "don't assign it an explicit value" would work. Look at my other question, where I do not assign it a specific value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279064/issue-with-static-code-in-android

Comment: OK, I've removed that bit.

Comment: Thanks for the update. My issue with enums is that I need to build up some hierarchies.